# Angular 2 RxJS Does the Zip Operator have a limit on arguments?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I'm mystified right now on what's causing this bug.  I am trying to zip the result of 7 Observables like:

```
var zipped$ = Observable.zip(
    Observable.of({prop1:1}),
    Observable.of({prop2:2}),
    Observable.of({prop3:3}),
    Observable.of({prop4:4}),
    Observable.of({prop5:5}),
    Observable.of({prop6:6}),
    Observable.of({prop7:7})
);
```

And then merge them with mergeAll() and reduce() like:

```
var reduced$ = zipped$.mergeAll().reduce((acc,val) => Object.assign({},acc,val));
reduced$.subscribe(final => console.log(final));
```

But I get this error: "property 'reduce' does not exist on type '{}'"

To add to the confusion:

If I use 6 values, it works fine.

If the observables all return primitives, it works fine.

if I add this function as the final argument in my zip:

```
function(...args: any[]) {
    // I have no ieda why I need this hack, but the zip fails without it.
    return args;
}
```

it works fine.

Is this a bug in RxJS? Am I missing something about the zip implementation? Is this an angular compiler thing?? No amount of searching docs has revealed a limit on the number of arguments to zip. Any insight is appreciated.

Thanks

EDIT: for any one else who finds this.

the best work around is to just stick the observables in an array and feed it as a single argument like:

```
var zipped$ = Observable.zip(...[
    Observable.of({prop1:1}),
    Observable.of({prop2:2}),
    Observable.of({prop3:3}),
    Observable.of({prop4:4}),
    Observable.of({prop5:5}),
    Observable.of({prop6:6}),
    Observable.of({prop7:7})]);
```

which also works fine. EDIT: the array feed stopped working, now need to use spread operator and array.

Comment: It's TypeScript related. Note that the explicitly typed overloads only go up to `T6`: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/operator/zip.ts After that, it'll match the signature with the variable arguments. Exactly what's going on, I don't know. I might have a look into it later.

Comment: That at least clarifies what's happening. I feel like this should at a minimum be in the docs.  Thanks for the insight, much appreciated. I'll mark this as answered if you make it an answer.

Comment: I'll post an answer when I know exactly what's going on. That fact that it's okay when you specify a project function suggests that there might be a missing overload signature.

Comment: Sounds good, love to see what you find.  I posted this to GitHub as well. Someone there responded and it turns out it also works if you just feed an array of observables to zip as a single argument instead of passing each as a separate argument.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of things had changed since 2017, the `rxjs` documentation nowadays is very good and covers pretty much everything that one may desire.

Now let's dive into the question.

First thing first the old `zip` operator (which can be found here: [old zip](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/6.x/src/internal/operators/zip.ts) ) is now deprecated in favor of the new `zip` (which can be found here: [zip](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/observable/zip.ts))

The main difference is that the old one was a chainable operator that was used like so (later on it became pipe-able):

```
of(1).pipe( zip(of(2)),map(([a,b]) => ({a,b}))).subscribe(x => console.log(x) // {a:1, b:2})
```

While the new one is a creational operator and is used like so:

```
zip(of(1),of(2)).pipe(delay(1000),map(([a,b]) => ({a,b}))).subscribe(x => console.log(x) // {a:1, b:2})
```

Now about the question, there is no limitation to the number of observables that you can pass in the zip opertor, for exmaple the following snippet will work

```
let arr = (new Array(100)).fill(false).map((x,i)=> of({[`key${i}`]:i}))
zip(...arr).pipe(
  mergeAll(),
  reduce((acc,val) => Object.assign({},acc,val)),
)
```

However if you are using typescript and are passing more than 6 observables of different types you will lose the typeings and autocompletion.